# GCP Batch with Instance Template fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run a Compute Engine Instance Template using the Batch API. It works without issues as a regular Compute Engine instance. However running it using Batch and Workflows it terminates after 10-15 minutes. Here is my Workflow:

```
main:
  params: [args]
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - projectId: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
          - region: "us-central1"
          - batchApi: "batch.googleapis.com/v1"
          - batchApiUrl: ${"https://" + batchApi + "/projects/" + projectId + "/locations/" + region + "/jobs"}
          - jobId: ${"fm-" + string(int(sys.now()))}
    - createAndRunBatchJob:
        call: http.post
        args:
          url: ${batchApiUrl}
          query:
            job_id: ${jobId}
          headers:
            Content-Type: application/json
          auth:
            type: OAuth2
          body:
            taskGroups:
              taskSpec:
                runnables:
                  - script:
                      text: "echo Hello world! This is task ${BATCH_TASK_INDEX}."
              taskCount: 1
              parallelism: 1
            allocationPolicy:
                instances:
                    - instanceTemplate: "updateservice-11"
            logsPolicy:
              destination: CLOUD_LOGGING
        result: createAndRunBatchJobResponse
    - getJob:
        call: http.get
        args:
          url: ${batchApiUrl + "/" + jobId}
          auth:
            type: OAuth2
        result: getJobResult
    - logState:
        call: sys.log
        args:
          data: ${"Current job state " + getJobResult.body.status.state}
    - checkState:
        switch:
          - condition: ${getJobResult.body.status.state == "SUCCEEDED"}
            next: returnResult
          - condition: ${getJobResult.body.status.state == "FAILED"}
            next: failExecution
        next: sleep
    - sleep:
        call: sys.sleep
        args:
          seconds: 10
        next: getJob
    - returnResult:
        return:
          jobId: ${jobId}
    - failExecution:
        raise:
          message: ${"The underlying batch job " + jobId + " failed"}
```

I also noticed that the Execution state is stuck at SCHEDULED for the entire time, before it fails after 10-15mins.
When it fails is see the following in the instance log:

```
{
insertId: "1ojqzgde8yq"
logName: "projects/XXXXX/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
operation: {3}
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
authenticationInfo: {1}
methodName: "v1.compute.instances.delete"
request: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/compute.instances.delete"
}
requestMetadata: {1}
resourceName: "projects/XXXXXXX/zones/us-central1-a/instances/j-1aaa7f73-3865-45a7-b0ea-fea8eeaa68a2-group0-0-s97m"
serviceName: "compute.googleapis.com"
}
receiveTimestamp: "2022-10-10T20:28:36.519771048Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "NOTICE"
timestamp: "2022-10-10T20:28:36.119832Z"
}
```

Comment: I narrowed down the error to this:
Oct 12 18:04:51 ... : Found startup-script in metadata.

Oct 12 18:04:51 ... : startup-script: [Batch Startup] Unsupported COS image.

Oct 12 18:04:51 ... : startup-script exit status 200